# Ubuntu hostapd slow download speed

Tags: networking, hostapd

I have setup a wireless access point on one of my old laptops using hostapd, the laptop in question uses a "Intel Wireless Centrino N-1030" with a rated download speed of 300mbps and a rated upload speed of 150mbps.

The access point is working fine but I'm only getting about 15mbps (according to speedtest) download speed instead of the 50mbps my actual router gives me. The upload speed is higher however (4mbps vs 3mbps).

I did a speedtest on the laptop and it hit that 50mbps via ethernet so that can't be the problem. My phone is telling me that the link speed is 65mbps which is just slightly lower than my routers 72mbps.

This is the script I used to set it up: https://gist.github.com/dashohoxha/5767262

Here are the contents of my hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlp3s0
driver=nl80211
ssid=NKBuildServer
hw_mode=g
wme_enabled=1
ieee80211n=1
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=1234567890
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

If I set hw_mode to n instead of g, the service starts but the access point doesn't show up on any of my devices even though it's a bgn wireless card.

Is there any way I can increase the speed of this access point?

Thanks!